Simple button recomposes on hovering according to LayoutInspector
I have this quite simple code:
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Sandbox()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Sandbox() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(16.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(24.dp)
    ) {
        Button(onClick = { /* TODO */ }) {
            Text("click me")
        }
    }
}

As soon as I am only hovering with the mouse over the button, it recomposes (note how the value 24 in the recompose column increases up to 57).
Why is that? Is that expected behaviour?

Update
When I remove MyTheme the issue does not occur, though I don't understand why it occurs with MyTheme, which is not modified by me:
That is my Theme.kt:
private val DarkColorScheme = darkColorScheme(
    primary = Purple80,
    secondary = PurpleGrey80,
    tertiary = Pink80
)

private val LightColorScheme = lightColorScheme(
    primary = Purple40,
    secondary = PurpleGrey40,
    tertiary = Pink40

    /* Other default colors to override
    background = Color(0xFFFFFBFE),
    surface = Color(0xFFFFFBFE),
    onPrimary = Color.White,
    onSecondary = Color.White,
    onTertiary = Color.White,
    onBackground = Color(0xFF1C1B1F),
    onSurface = Color(0xFF1C1B1F),
    */
)

@Composable
fun MyTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    // Dynamic color is available on Android 12+
    dynamicColor: Boolean = true,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colorScheme = when {
        dynamicColor && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S -> {
            val context = LocalContext.current
            if (darkTheme) dynamicDarkColorScheme(context) else dynamicLightColorScheme(context)
        }

        darkTheme -> DarkColorScheme
        else -> LightColorScheme
    }
    val view = LocalView.current
    if (!view.isInEditMode) {
        SideEffect {
            val window = (view.context as Activity).window
            window.statusBarColor = colorScheme.primary.toArgb()
            WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = darkTheme
        }
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = colorScheme,
        typography = Typography,
        content = content
    )
}


I cannot reproduce that behavior. Does it also happen when you remove MyTheme?

Also, is that a hover effect or is it just the layout inspector adding some decoration?

it's the layout inspector highlighting the recomposition.

@Leviathan added update. not happening when removing MyTheme, though I don't understand how the theme causes recomposition. Added Theme.kt to my question.

Still not reproducible. Can you create a new project from scratch using the Empty Activity template in Android Studio, and just copy the activity and the composable? And the Theme.kt

How are your colors defined? What happens when you remove them?

I can't reproduce in a new project and also not anymore in my original project since I removed and re-added the MyTheme. Can't explain that to myself, wondering if the Layout Inspector got something wrong internally, but no chance to further dig into this. Thanks for your support here, somehow helped me to fix it :-)

I can't reproduce in a new project and also not anymore in my original project since I removed and re-added the MyTheme. Can't explain that to myself, wondering if the Layout Inspector got something wrong internally, but no chance to further dig into this.
